# Insert random elements of array into another array with specific index in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

So I have an array of names like this:

```
String[] arrayOfName = {"Elephant", "Deer", "Fish", "Crocodile", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Butterfly", "Chicken", "Ant", "Snake", "Lion", "Horse", "Wolf", "Panda", "Swan", "Lobster"};
```

I was thinking about if have another array, and I wanna put between 4 to 10 (it's random) random names from `arrayOfName` into my new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Random` class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] arrayOfName = {"Elephant", "Deer", "Fish", "Crocodile", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Butterfly", "Chicken", "Ant", "Snake", "Lion", "Horse", "Wolf", "Panda", "Swan", "Lobster"};

        // this will give you a random value between 4 (inclusive) and 11 (exclusive, or 10 inclusive)
        int numberOfRandomValues = rand.nextInt(7) + 4;

        String[] newArrayOfName =  new String[numberOfRandomValues];

        for(int  i = 0; i < numberOfRandomValues; i++) {
            // this will give you a random value between 0 (inclusive) and the size of array (inclusive as well) which you can use to add a random element
            int randomPosition = rand.nextInt(arrayOfName.length);
            newArrayOfName[i] = arrayOfName[randomPosition];
            System.out.println(" - Just added " + newArrayOfName[i] + " on position " + i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In `nextInt()` the upperBound parameter is exclusive. So `rand.nextInt(6)` cannot never return `6`.

Comment: @davidxxx I already had a comment saying that: `// this will give you a random value between 4 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive)`. I think that can very easily be changed, the explanation is more important.

Comment: @davidxxx Fixed now according to your comment, for precision.

Comment: It is always better to stay specific to the question in our answer if it is easy to do it :)

Comment: @davidxxx Totally agree ;)

Answer (score 1):

First step : you could use a Random object and generate a number between 4 and 10.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int minElementToTake = 4;
    int maxElementsToTake = 10;
    int nbElementToTake = random.nextInt(maxElementsToTake - minElementToTake + 1) + minElementToTake;
```

Here `random.nextInt()` generates a number between 0 and 6. Then, we add 4 to it.
So `int nbElementToTake` is `>= 4 && <=10`.

Second step : iterate "`nbElementToTake`" times and use still the nextInt() method to generate an int between 0 and the original array size.
In this way, you will have an int representing a random index of the original array and you could retrieve so a random element from it to store it in your target array.

NB : In the proposed solution, I have added a Set to avoid adding multiple times the same value in the target array. It is not an effective way to handle this concern but for a array with not a lot data, it is acceptable.
By using a List instead of an array, we could have a more efficient and easy solution for this concern.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class AnimalRandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayOfName = { "Elephant", "Deer", "Fish", "Crocodile", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Butterfly", "Chicken",
                "Ant", "Snake", "Lion", "Horse", "Wolf", "Panda", "Swan", "Lobster" };

        Random random = new Random();
        int minElementToTake = 4;
        int maxElementsToTake = 10;
        int nbElementToTake = random.nextInt(maxElementsToTake - minElementToTake + 1) + minElementToTake;

        String[] newArray = new String[nbElementToTake];

        Set<Integer> indexesUsed = new HashSet<>();
        Random randomOrder = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbElementToTake; i++) {

            int maxInclusive = arrayOfName.length;

            int indexToUse = randomOrder.nextInt(maxInclusive);

            while (indexesUsed.contains(indexToUse)) {
                indexToUse = randomOrder.nextInt(maxInclusive);
            }
            indexesUsed.add(indexToUse);
            newArray[i] = arrayOfName[indexToUse];
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not tested, but came up with a stub for this requirement -

```
/**
 * To pick any few sequential input strings from the list of inputs
 * @param inputArr input array of strings
 * @param few number of strings to be picked up
 * @return any random sequence of x strings from input
 */
public static String[] randomSequenceOfFewStrings(String[] inputArr, int few) {
    String[] outputArr = new String[few];
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(inputArr.length - few);
    for (int i = 0; i < few; i++) {
        outputArr[i] = inputArr[index];
        index++;
    }
    return outputArr;
}
```

wherein you can use the same code for your use case as -

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomSequenceOfFewStrings(arrayOfName, 5)));
```

*Note* - This should generate a different sequence of fixed number of elements for every call with same arguments and different sequence of different number of elements for every different method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String[] arrayOfName = {"Elephant", "Deer", "Fish", "Crocodile", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Butterfly", "Chicken", "Ant", "Snake", "Lion", "Horse", "Wolf", "Panda", "Swan", "Lobster"};
        List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfName));     // convert array to list
        Collections.shuffle(listOfNames);                                           // shuffle the list
        Random ran = new Random();
        List<String> listOfRandomNames = new ArrayList<>(listOfNames.subList(0, 4 + ran.nextInt(6)));   // pick random number of strings from the shuffled list
        String[] arrayOfRandomNames = new String[listOfRandomNames.size()];     // new Array with size of random list
        arrayOfRandomNames = listOfRandomNames.toArray(arrayOfRandomNames);     // convert list to array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfRandomNames));                // print or do whatever
    }   
}
```